# Summing the values of one column of one row from two tables into third table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

That title sounds really confusing, so let me show what I need.

`table1`:

```
name  number
Bob   6
Linda 8
Tina  3
```

`table2`:

```
name  number
Bob   9
Linda 2
Tina  1
```

What I need is to sum the values of `number` into a third table (that already exists) so that it would look like this:

`table3`:

```
name  number
Bob   15
Linda 10
Tina  4
```

Excuse me if this has already been answered but I searched as well as I could and all of the answers were really specific to the question and didn't quite do what I need.

**Edit:** `table3` is currently entirely blank. It just shares the same structure as `table1` and `table2`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how you do it:

```
insert into table3 (name, number)
    select t.name, sum(t.number) as totalNumber
    from (
       select name, number from table1 
       union
       select name, number from table2
       union
       select name, number from table3
    ) t
    group by t.name
```

If you want the summry data for specific `name`, you can add this where clause above the `group by` like this:

```
where t.name = 'Bob'
```

Comment: In order to insert into table 3 add `INSERT table3 (name, number)` as first line.

Comment: I should've mentioned in my post I have next to no knowledge of MySQL. How exactly would I go about actually inserting this data into `table3`? Keep in mind, `table3` is entirely blank, it just has the same structure as `table1` and `table2`.

Comment: it's very simply (combine `insert into` with `select`), i've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

if you already have table3 with all names you can do with below query with using loop with all names.

```
insert into table3 (number) values (select (t1.number + t2.number) from table1 inner join table2 on t1.name = t2.name where t1.name = 'Bob')
```

otherwise you need to write procedure.

Comment: Why not a `select` + `union` + `group by`?

Comment: you are right @Latheesan Kanes

Answer (score 0):

**your Expected Result...!!! (Simple and sort query)**

```
          INSERT INTO table3 (name,number)
          SELECT t.name, sum(t.number) as number
          FROM (
              SELECT name, number from table1 
              UNION
              SELECT name, number from table2
          ) t
          GROUP BY t.name
```

**Result:-**

> **table3:**
>
> ```
>           name    number
>           Bob      15
>           Linda    10
>           Tina     4
> ```

Comment: sorry, i had to ask; did you just copy my answer? lol.

Comment: No,Dear..!!
actually you are write and post answer i am search and execute query in my database and finally find query and post then after your answer checked. So...sorry.